# Command external field value to be sent with form

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, css

I have two forms on one page.

The first form is used to make a calculation (fieldvalue1 + fieldvalue2 = **calculatedfield**)
The second form is simply just to capture information (Name, Email, etc.)

The first form has no submit button, but the second form has a submit button. Currently, when the user fills in all the info and clicks submit, then only the second form's fields get sent to my admin email.

Is there a way to send **calculatedfield** along with the form fields sent to my email when clicking the submit button on the second form?

I would like to add a code snippet to command the **calculatedfield** to also be sent along with the fields of the second form. Not sure which code to use...

I would greatly appreciate any assistance.

Comment: What is the point in having the first form without a submit button? Couldn't you just include all your inputs inside the same `<form>` tag?

Comment: Hi @Balastrong, I'm figuring this out for someone that is using two different form plugins.

Comment: You need to submit values from the first form and capture them as hidden fields in the second form. So, as soon as you hit submit on the second form all values on second form including the hidden values will be sent.

Comment: Check if there is any jquery function call that executes when one clicks the next button/link on the first form. Mostly that should be your starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Add a new hidden field (lets call it hiddenCalculatedField) to your second form.

In the first form, add a onChange hook to the **calculatedfield**, and copy the value to the hidden field. This will get submitted when the second form is submitted.

In this example, it assumes

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("input[name='calculatedfield']").change(function() {
       $("input[name='hiddenCalculatedField']").val($(this).val())
   })
}
```

Comment: Hi @Catch22, thanks for your response. The two forms are from two different plugins. I was hoping I could simply add a code snippet to command the **calculatedfield** to be sent with the second form. I've added the hidden field to the second form. Not sure how to add an onChange hook in the first form. Thanks so much for helping.

Comment: If you look at the first form using the developer tools => Inspect element (in Chrome) you will be able to find the identifier for the first form (either the form ID, form class, or the ID/class of the calculatedField input element), then you can use jQuery to target that input field and call the change() hook.